# excluding some files from Build in Scons

Tags: python, makefile, scons

Since I am a newbie in Scons, I am finding it difficult to migrate my existing Makefile to Scons.

**Background:**
I have 50 files in a directory.I want to filter files only with *.cxx extension, that too filenames without string "win32" .

Can somebody suggest an implementation for this logic in Scons :

Makefile Implementation :

```
WIN32FILTER = $(wildcard *win32*)
CXXOBJS = $(patsubst %.cxx,%.o,$(filter-out $(WIN32FILTER),$(wildcard *.cxx)))
```

In Scons ,I am trying something like this :

```
moduleSources = ''
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.cxx'):
        if "win32" not in filename:
            moduleSources += ' ' + filename  

env.StaticLibrary( "support_host", moduleSources)
```

**moduleSources** here should contain list of all *.cxx files (excluding *win32* string) which will be used to make a Static library.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Entirely unfamiliar with Scons myself but it looks like the `Glob` function might be what you want here. Possibly something like `Glob('*.cxx') - Glob('*win32*')` if Glob supports subtraction. If not then a filter or comprehension over that first `Glob`'s results should do what you want (there are other SO answers about doing this).

Comment: etan - You should post that as an answer. It's better than using os.walk..

Answer (score 0):

You create a single string with spaces in it to describe the set of source code files. This doesn't do what you hoped.

Instead, create a list of filenames. The following SConstruct does what you want:

```
import os
import fnmatch

env = Environment()

moduleSources = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('./'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.cxx'):
        if "win32" not in filename:
            moduleSources.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

env.StaticLibrary( "support_host", moduleSources)
```